# como hago para depurar o iniciar sin depurar en visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, depuración

Hola acabo de instalarme visual studio para utilizar c# pero en la opción para depurar o iniciar sin depurar me aparecen cambiadas. en la opción para iniciar sin depurar directamente no me deja seleccionarla y en la opción para depurar me aparece para adjuntar y darle me abre una pestaña para asociar algun proceso y la verdad nose que debo hacer.[image: En esta imagen se ve que en la flechita verde dice adjuntar y en la otra le falta su contorno verde]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.